Extremely simple parser with boost::spirit fails
I always fail with spirit parsers, this time I am trying to figure out how to achieve an extremely simple goal: Parse three words into a tuple of 3 strings - I don't even manage to get this working and feel very stupid now.
Its about this little bit of code:
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>

namespace {
    using namespace boost::spirit;
}

int main () {

    const std::string_view content {"some second last"};
    std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> words;

    auto atInput = content.begin ();
    const auto endOfInput = content.end ();

    bool result = qi::phrase_parse (atInput,
                                    endOfInput,
                                    +qi::char_ >> +qi::char_ >> +qi::char_,
                                    qi::ascii::space,
                                    words);

    if (result) {
        const auto& [first, second, last] = words;
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded: " << first << " - " << second << " - " << last
                  << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error in parsing.\n";
    }
}

I get Error in parsing and I have no clue why. What is wrong with this simple example?

Your skipper removes the spaces. Therefore, the parser really sees "somesecondlast". That matches the first +char_, which means the entire expression fails to parse because EOI is reached.
You can make this explicitly visible by using rule debugging:
Live On Coliru
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG 1
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using Tuple  = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>;
using It     = std::string_view::const_iterator;

int main() {
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), qi::space_type> word_ = +qi::char_;
    qi::rule<It, Tuple(), qi::space_type>       rule  = word_ >> word_ >> word_;
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((word_)(rule));

    for (std::string_view content : {"some second last"}) {
        Tuple words;
        auto  f = content.begin(), l = content.end();
        if (qi::phrase_parse(f, l, rule, qi::space, words)) {
            auto const& [w1, w2, w3] = words;
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded: " << quoted(w1) << " - " << quoted(w2) << " - " << quoted(w3) << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Error in parsing.\n";
        }
    }
}

Printing
<rule>
  <try>some second last</try>
  <word_>
    <try>some second last</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[s, o, m, e, s, e, c, o, n, d, l, a, s, t]]</attributes>
  </word_>
  <word_>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </word_>
  <fail/>
</rule>
Error in parsing.

Lexemes
You can get around this in many ways. I describe how lexemes, skippers and non-terminal parsers (like qi::rule) interact here: Boost spirit skipper issues
In my debug example, the simplest would be to drop the skipper from the word_ rule declaration:
qi::rule<It, std::string() /*, qi::space_type*/> word_ = +qi::graph;


Note that qi::graph must now be used to avoid matching space

Printing Live On Coliru:
Parsing succeeded: "some" - "second" - "last"

Other approaches, perhaps without the rules, may be:
if (qi::phrase_parse(                                                               //
        f, l,                                                                       //
        qi::lexeme[+qi::graph] >> qi::lexeme[+qi::graph] >> qi::lexeme[+qi::graph], //
        qi::space,                                                                  //
        words))

Or not using a skipper in the first place:
    if (qi::parse(                                                                                  //
            f, l,                                                                                   //
            +qi::graph >> qi::omit[*qi::space] >> +qi::graph >> qi::omit[*qi::space] >> +qi::graph, //
            words))

I'd personally consider simplifying down to something like: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0dce7bb8be31f9f

Thanks a lot! Skipping really always puzzles me. In my naive understanding I would assume that the skipper skips until and after those characters that are not whitespace and it would distinguish between whitespace and not whitespace. So there would be characters - whitespace - characters - whitespace - characters. The fact that I have to use lexeme on characters (that don't include any whitespace) is confusing to me. If there is some explanation for dummies like me how this behaves in detail (so I can imagine how it works) I would be happy and probably feeling less stupid.

I should re-read the linked answer to see if it needs more work, but in my memory it does explain

I guess the only thing that you need to realize in addition to the docs ("The skip parser is the one responsible for skipping characters in between parser elements such as the double_ and char_. ") is that +p is not "atomic": so it is actually like +(*skipper >> p >> *skipper) where in your case p == char_. If you don't want that, you need to inhibit the pre/post skipper (no_skip, lexeme) or declare a skipper-less rule (I call them lexemes)

Ahhh! Now I definitely feel stupid - I declared the content as a multiple of characters, so of course the skipper affects all of instances between those single characters as well - and it eats up all white-space between any characters and as a result I get all characters without white-space stuffed into one collection of characters. Everything makes sense now.

No need to feel stupid. It's how learning works! Learning to celebrate the "feeling stupid" sensation really helped my mental health. In fact, I accelerate towards it, and it really speeds up learning because you get attracted to anything that doesn't feel completely clear/ever so slightly surprising. It's "fail early" applied to learning. The failing is a requisite step. Of course, sometimes, the thing you're trying to grok is actually defective.
